# How to match italics and underlining in regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm wondering whether italicization can be matched in regex. Suppose I have these strings:

> ex <- c("what *did* you do?", "i don’t know", "*Pe*ter is angry.")

What regex would match strings 1 and 3? Also, supposing "did" and "Pe" were not italicized but **underlined**, what regex would match the respective strings? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't write italics/underlines in character vectors (unless you write them in a markup language)

Comment: As far as I know, regex is for matching unformatted text. How would formatted strings be stored? If there are tags before and after the text then the tags can be matched. EG: for the string ` <i> Hello </i> ` , you could use the pattern `"\\<i\\>.*\\<\\i\\>"`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your input string? `ex <- c("what did you do?", "i don’t know", "Peter is angry.")` does not have any information on how italics or underlining are implemented. Then, what have *you* tried? What is the programming issue you want to solve?

Comment: My question is unclear: really? I have avoided highlighting the input data as code on purpose on the grounds that the italicization then disappears; in the format given by me, it is intact. Re your question what I have tried: honestly, nothing so far! I did some research on the question only to find practically nothing. And the above two comments e.g. by @Rohit seem to point in the same direction: maybe regex cannot handle font formatting!

Comment: Like I said earlier, regex matches the raw string, i.e. the actual ANSI/ UTF-8 character. Italics and other formatting have a start and stop tag, which is what you'll have to search for. This will differ depending on the format of the file. So, please: in your file, what differentiates formatted text from unformatted text. If you print it out in R, what do you see in plain text?

Comment: Using the above mock example this is the output in R: `ex <- c("what did you do?", "i don’t know", "Peter is angry.")`
`ex`
`[1] "what did you do?" "i don’t know"     "Peter is angry."`